# Dotnet run command issues

Tags: .net, api

I'm trying to build and run web API project using dotnet run command but I'm  getting the below error .

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you provide any additional information to help us help you? What does the project file look like? Where could paths like `C:\Users\khalid\source` be coming from?

Comment: The error is in fact caused by build failures, so you should run `dotnet build -bl` to generate MSBuild bin log https://msbuildlog.com/ That log file contains all the details on what's wrong.

Comment: It's messing up relative and absolute paths. Did you adapt paths in the solution or cs proj file?